# how to write % in a string format in Java - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show a percentage but how do I show % sign using string format?
Here's my line of code

```
precent.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%.1f", precentNum))
```

I mean how do I put a percentage sign at the end of the text? couldn't find an answer when I searched.

Comment: `%%` is the answer - and the word is _percentage_, not _precentage_.

Comment: no, then it shows ".1f" instead of the number.

Comment: Use `"%.1f%%"` as your format string.  The `%%` shows up as `%`.

Comment: oh I thought at the start, thanks :)
sorry for the ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try %% instead of %. It will display a single % in your string.

Comment: no, that does not work, it shows ".1f" as the text.
nvm, I realize what you meant, thanks, it works :)

Comment: Happy to help :) .. Here on SO we mark the answer as right which solves the problem.